# React Native Pixel Density issue with Pixel 2 XL (react-native-device-info)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-device-info

Apparently when you set your device's display size to small react-native-device-info library thought that it's a tablet and according to that all the layouts and everything starting to act like tablets and my images aren't visible anymore. Does anyone having the same problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it. With this new high density phones for example Google Pixel 2 XL or nexus or something like that some phone that you can change your display size to small. When you do that react native behave that your phone is a tablet and showing the tablet layout on that phone. So I actually checked some of the devices densities and there is not a single tablet over 2.0 density.

```
 PixelRatio.get() < 2 ? DeviceInfo.isTablet : () => false
```

This is working for me if anyone is intrested.